# How to encrypt data using rsa public key in php

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

Receiver has given me a public key and I need to use it to encrypt username and password. I have done various r&d but nothing works.
I have used

```
function public_encrypt($plaintext)
{
    $fp=fopen("private.key","r");
    $pub_key=fread($fp,8192);
    fclose($fp);
    openssl_get_publickey($pub_key);
    openssl_public_encrypt($plaintext,$crypttext, $pub_key);
    return(base64_encode($crypttext));
}
```

But it gives me `openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key` error.

I have also added begin and end line to key, but still no success
Kindly guide me with steps to follow as I am new in it.

Comment: $pubkey=openssl_get_publickey($pub_key);

Comment: I have tried it. used that $pubkey in encryption, still no success. Still getting same error. please help.

Comment: The get publickey needs the certificate file

Comment: which certificate file? please guide me. they have just mailed me text file containing a public key.

Comment: How does this file look like?

Comment: Its publickey.txt file with following text data in it. "BgIAAACkAABSU0ExAAQAAAEAAQBNSbsNLg+hMtCBpjOMF4EkqysbYaV8bDDQXq0Xm+EECyNeDug/O/KajxncM7fiRfrnvpbjXMLfSei1GdT1NQHjVm1pOmbmnYyBKvZqxtXYbtdk7SepHFgozoYKiwEHfBUUK3e/dyr/IBV334++npIWhTlIDgJN/1EXPNJrZYWKyg==" I have just change its name and format to private.key

Comment: A public key starts with ----PUBLIC KEY START---- and ends with ----PUBLIC KEY END----

Comment: still no luck. I have already use it before. Is their anything I have to use as library? If yes then please guide.

Comment: It's interesting that you named your **public key** as *private.key*. The problem here is that you didn't receive properly formatted key. The second part of the problem is that you can't encrypt any amount of data with public key, there's a limit and it's rather small. Public/private key cryptography is usually used to transmit a symmetric key between two parties. If I were you, I'd ask for a PEM formatted public key so you don't have to go through the process of trying to coerce it yourself into what openssl understands.

Comment: Also, @Jonasw - where did you read that public key starts with `----PUBLIC KEY START----`? That's not the correct delimiter in any of the encoding formats.

Comment: @MjhPhp.net says that openssl_get_publickey() needs a public key in PEM format. And the PEM format has got this.

Comment: @Jonasw - it doesn't, it uses a different delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to decode a key that is not in any known format it seems. I presume it has been made by somebody that does not fully understand crypto, as it has a 1023 bit modulus.

If you look at the hexadecimal representation you'll find a modulus with a value of:

```
4D49BB0D2E0FA132D081A6338C178124AB2B1B61A57C6C30D05EAD179BE1040B235E0EE83F3BF29A8F19DC33B7E245FAE7BE96E35CC2DF49E8B519D4F53501E3566D693A66E69D8C812AF66AC6D5D86ED764ED27A91C5828CE860A8B01077C15142B77BF772AFF201577DF8FBE9E92168539480E024DFF51173CD26B65858ACA
```

(simply the last value within the structure with a size close to 1024 bits) and a public exponent with a value

```
010001
```